# Select a div inside a parent two levels up?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some hidden sections which expand when an arrow is clicked. The arrow used to be a part of the main "questionBlock" div, so we used `$content = $arrow.siblings(.questionBlockExpand)` to select the section to expand. But now with some required layout changes, the arrow is now apart of the title which is within another div called "questionBlockTitle".

I am having trouble selecting the "questionBlockExpand" which is now within the parent div 2 levels up.

The JQuery code below is one of my attempts to select div via the 2nd parent level.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

HTML:

```
<div class='questionBlock testing123 '>
    <div class='questionBlockTitle'><span class='sectionQuestionBlockNumber'>1</span><span class='sectionQuestionBlockTitle'>title text</span>
        <div class='expandArrow downArrow'>Expand Arrow Image</div>
    </div>
    <div class='questionBlockExpand'>Section to expand</div>
</div>
```

JQuery:

```
$(".expandArrow").click(function () {

$arrow = $(this);
$content = $arrow.parent().parent(".questionBlockExpand");
//open up the content needed - toggle the slide- if visible, slide up, if not slidedown.
$content.slideToggle(500, function () {
    //execute this after slideToggle is done
    //change class of header based on visibility of content div
    if ($content.is(":visible")) {
        $arrow.addClass("upArrowBlock");
        $arrow.removeClass("downArrowBlock");
    } else {
        $arrow.addClass("downArrowBlock");
        $arrow.removeClass("upArrowBlock");
    }
});
```

});

Comment: `$content = $arrow.closest('.questionBlock ').find(".questionBlockExpand");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `closest()` to traverse up to container `questionBlock` div the use `find()`

```
$content = $arrow.closest('.questionBlock ').find(".questionBlockExpand");
```

OR,

```
$content = $arrow.closest('.questionBlockTitle').next(".questionBlockExpand");
//$content = $arrow.parent().next(".questionBlockExpand");
```

OR

```
$content = $arrow.closest('.questionBlockTitle').siblings(".questionBlockExpand");
//$content = $arrow.parent().siblings(".questionBlockExpand");
```

Comment: I tried using .next() to achieve this, but that didn't work. I'll try with closest, but wasn't sure if it was best practice to do this. As there are going to be multiple sections like this on the page, not sure how it chooses which is closest.

Comment: Your edit with parent().siblings suddenly makes sense!

Comment: Tried with Parent().siblings and it works exactly how I was trying. But seems you edited this one out of your answer.

Comment: @user2924019, I have added it back, there are different ways of traversing the DOM

Comment: Many thanks. Will mark as correct as soon as it allows me to.